Integral over a sphere in $R^n$
Let $\sigma$ be the Lebesgue measure on the unit sphere  $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ of $\mathbb R^n$.
Let $\Sigma$ be a semi-definite positive symmetric matrix in dimension $n$.
Is it possible to get a closed-form expression for the following integral:
$$\int_{u \in \mathbb S^{n-1}} \left(u'\Sigma u\right)^{\frac 12} \ \sigma(du)$$

Is $u'$ meant to be $u^T$ (ie. the transpose)? Would you know how to do it if $\Sigma$ was diagonal (I guess one can just make a change of variables to diagonalize our matrix, but I do not quite see how to do the diagonal case)?
